# Are there any MVVM-like frameworks for objective-c on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, model-view-controller, mvvm

Are there any MVVM frameworks for Objective-C that are widely used on iOS (iPhone/iPad)?

I'm a .net developer who has just started with iOS (read tutorials, done a couple of simple test apps), and from first perspective iOS's MVC looks to me pretty much like WinForms (correct me please if I'm wrong). WinForms "evolved" to WPF with MVVM, making Separation of Concerns way easier.

Are there something similar to MVVM for iOS? In the MonoTouch world I saw at least [mvvmcross](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross) applying MVVM. What about Objective-C? Or generally there's no need for this in iOS world?

Comment: Not sure why this question was closed... but for what it's worth you might want to check out this blog post http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2013/03/basic-mvvm-with-reactivecocoa.html

Comment: EasyIOS is what you need  https://github.com/zhuchaowe/EasyIOS

Answer (score 3):

MvvmCross relies heavily on reflection, and on public c# properties and events. I did look at the idea of trying to extend the framework into objC and uikit, but really the structure of its function/selector API didn't seem to lend itself nicely to the databinding part of mvvm

Comment: What about reactive cocoa, does it add required data binding capabilities?

Comment: ReactiveCocoa can be a useful adjunct to MVVM, but is not itself an MVVM framework.